# Convex function with convex and compact domain attains maximum

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, compactness

I know that if convex function $f: \Omega \rightarrow R$ is continuous and $\Omega$ is compact and convex, then $f$ attains its maximum. Now what if $f$ is not continuous, will f attains its maximum as well? If so, then how to prove it (I need a formal proof or draft of a formal proof)? If not, then why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not true. Consider the closed disk of radius $1$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$. If $f=0$ in the open disk and $f \geq 0$ on the boundary then $f$ is convex. Since the boundary values are completely arbitrary it is is obvious that it need not attain its maximum. I will let you write down a counter-example explicitly.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still wondering what if $\Omega$ is in $R$, that is to say $\Omega$ is a closed interval? Will this be true?

Comment: @Walls If $\Omega$ is a closed interval in $\mathbb R$ then $f$ will attain its maximum.

Comment: Would you please provide a simple proof? Intuitively it's true but I'm just wondering a formal proof.

Comment: @Walls Some hints: I will consider the case where $f$  is convex on $[0,1]$ and continuous at $1$.  $t=(1-t)0+t1$ so $f(t) \leq (1-t)f(0)+tf(1)$. This shows that $f$ is necessarily bounded. Let $M$ be the supremum of $f$. If $f(0) \geq M$ we are done. Suppose $f(0) <M$. Then above inequality shows that $f<M$ in some interval $[0,r]$. Now use the fact $f$ attains its maximum on $[r,1]$ to finish the proof..

Comment: What I can think about is using the definition of convex function, let the interval be $[a, b]$ take $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then $f(ta+(1-t)b) \leq tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$ and $ta+(1-t)b$ can represent any point in the interval, thus, for any point $s$ in $\Omega$, we have $f(s)  \leq max\{tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)| t \in [0,1] \}$ and $max\{tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)| t \in [0,1] \}$ would be the maximum we want. Don't know if this works

Comment: I have posted a solution for the 1-dimensional case as it's too long for a comment. You can say that the reason it will not work in higher  dimensions is that it uses the fact that if U,V, W are 3 distinct reals then one of them is in the convex hull of the other 2, which is only valid in 1-D.

Answer (score 1):

This was meant to be a comment to the A by @Kavi Rama Murphy but is too long.

In the case $\Omega=[a,b]\subset \Bbb R$ with $a<b.$

1. Suppose $\infty>M=\sup_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)\ne \max_{x\in [a,b]}f(x).$

   Let $(x_n)_n$ be a monotonic sequence in $[a,b]$ converging to $y\in [a,b]$ with $(f(x_n))_n$ converging to $M$. Now $f(y)<M$ so let $f(y)=M-3r$ with $r>0.$

   Take $n_1$ with  $f(x_{n_1})>M-3r>f(y) .$ Note $x_{n_1}\ne y.$ Take $n_2$ with $|y-x_{n_2}|<|y-(y+x_{n_1})/2|$ and $f(x_{n_2})>M-r.$ Note $x_{n_2}\ne y.$ By the convexity of $f$ we have $$(i)...\quad f((y+x_{n_1})/2)\le (f(y)+f(x_{n_1}))/2\le ((M-3r)+M)/2<M-r<f(x_{n_2}).$$  $$(ii)..\quad f(y+x_{n_2})/2)\le (f(y)+f(x_{n_2}))/2<((M-3r)+M)/2<M-r<f(x_{n_2}).$$ Now $x_{n_2}$ is strictly between $A=(y+x_{n_2})/2$ and $B=(y+x_{n_1})/2$ but $f(x_{n_2})>\max (f(A),f(B)),$ contradicting the convexity of $f.$

Remark. $x_{n_2}$ is the lead actor. We could have started with $n_2$ with $f(x_{n_2})>M-r $ and with $|y-x_{n_2}|$ small enough  that there exists $z\in [a,b]$ with $x_{n_2}$ lying strictly between $y$ and $(y+z)/2,$ and replace $x_{n_1}$ with $z.$

I will leave it to the reader to show that $\sup_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)=\infty$ also leads to a contradiction.